# Error when creating an MVC controller using composite key and EF 5

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, composite-key

Using the Entity Framework tools I reverse engineered code first the POCO classes for a MySQL database into a class library. I created an MVC project that references this class library and I am trying to create a controller with read/write actions and views.  After setting the model and data context classes and clicking "Add" I get this error:

EntityType xxx has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

The problem is, in the map it is marked properly:

```
    public UserApplicationMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => new { t.UserID, t.AppID });
        ...
```

I tried doing this in the class:

```
public class UserApplication
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int AppID { get; set; }
```

But the compiler had a fit with the Column attribute and flagged it as invalid.

So I am a bit stumped. I really don't want to add an auto increment field to this table if I can just use a composite key.

I am using Visual Studio 2012, EF 5, MVC 4, and MySQL connector 6.6.4

Comment: Is the `UserApplicationMap` added to the `modelBuilder` configurations in `OnModelCreating`?

Comment: OK. That was the problem.  For some reason that line was missing from the Context.  Thanks for the heads-up.